# Remove dynamically created form elements using Jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have this code which works:

```
return form.find('input[name!=user_view]').serializeArray();
```

but I'd like to now also omit another input box I have added, but I can't work out how to remove multiple elements.

So I'd like to do something like this:

```
return form.find('input[name!=user_view],input[name!=client_view]').serializeArray();
```

but it doesn't work.

What's the correct function/syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
return form
          .find(':not(input[name=user_view],input[name=client_view])')
          .serializeArray();
```